# How to add dismissible alert in dashboard template?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am looking at the bootstrap template: 
http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/

I want this snippet of code to show up just below the top navigation bar, which has "home, settings, profile, help, etc.", but in the area where it says "Dashboard" and has the big circle images:

```
<div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success"> 
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> 
    <strong>Logged in!</strong> You Logged in!
</div>
```

But I can't figure out how to place it there!
If I place it just below the `header`, it gets obscured by the sidebar.
If I place it just above the `main` tag, then it doesn't appear fully for some reason.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I can help.

So in the boostrap dashboard [template](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/dashboard/) you're looking at, there's a few things about the layout of the elements that you should pay particular attention to.

1. The `<main>` element is where most of the content should be going
2. The `<main>` element is offset from the left side with a margin
3. The `<nav>` element immediately before the `<main>` lives within that margin space

This means that if you want to add any content so that it scrolls along with the rest of `<main>`, it should be added as a *child* of `<main>`. The reason that your alert gets obscured if you place it after the header, is that it isn't inside the container that comes after the top navbar. If you put it immediately before `<main>`, then it doesn't have the same margin to the left as `<main>` and will be placed under the vertical menu.

So what you would want to do is something like this:

```
<div className="container-fluid">
   <div className="row">
      <nav className="col-sm-3 col-md-2 d-none d-sm-block bg-light sidebar">...</nav>
      <main className="col-sm-9 ml-sm-auto col-md-10 pt-3" role="main">
         <h1>Dashboard</h1>

         <!-- This is where you can put your new code -->

         <section className="row text-center placeholder">
            <div class="alert alert-dismissible alert-success"> 
               <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> 
               <strong>Logged in!</strong> You Logged in!
            </div>
         </section>

         <!-- End your code -->

         <section className="row text-center placeholder">
         </section>
      </main>
   </div>
</div>
```

This way your new component lives in the main `<main>` section and scrolls with the rest of it, and it'll be above the colored circle section.